# Docker setting entrypoint when attaching volume -v

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Previously, I was able to attach a folder on my desktop as a **volume** in my container like so:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /Users/me/Desktop/Jupyter:/home/jovyan/work -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

However, when I run...

```
docker run -it -v /Users/me/Desktop/nfscripts:/usr nextflow/nextflow /bin/bash
```

... I get the following **error**:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/local/bin/entry.sh\": stat /usr/local/bin/entry.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

When I launch an interactive session and check the directory I get the base `/` and I can see `usr` directory.

```
$ docker run -it nextflow/nextflow /bin/bash
$ pwd
/
$ ls
bin  dev  etc  home  lib  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I recognize `/usr/local/bin/entry.sh` from the Cmd and it definitely exists because I can cat it.

```
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENTRYPOINT [\"/usr/local/bin/entry.sh\"]"
            ],
```

Am I not allowed to mount `:/usr` because it's in the path of the entry point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the specified entrypoint, which can be different from the directory your launch an interactive session into:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /Users/me/Desktop/nfscripts:/usr/local/bin/entry nextflow/nextflow /bin/bash
```